# Probability problem: winning a best-of-seven playoff in 5 games and losing the first.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My exam had the following prompt:

> A best-of-seven playoff is a competition between two teams head-to-head which must win four games to win the series. Four is
> chosen as it would constitute a majority of games played; whoever has
> won four games before all seven games have been played, all other
> games are omitted. Note that NBA finals are played based on best-of
> seven games series.
>
> We have two competing teams in a best-of-seven games series: Team A
> and Team B. The probability of Team A winning a game is $p$, and Team B
> winning a game is $1-p$ (no draw games) where $0 < p < 1$.
>
> Hint: The winner of the series has to win the last game.

One of the questions is based on this prompt and reads:

> We know that Team A won the series in five games (i.e, won 4-1). What is the probability of Team A losing the first game?

And here's how I solved it, but I only got 5/10 points for it, and I'm not sure what I did wrong exactly. The professor hasn't released the solutions yet, so I figured I'd ask here.

My solution:

> There is only one such outcome: LWWWW.
>
> Probability = $(1-p)p^4$

Why is this wrong? Since the prompt says the winner of the series has to win the last game, and we're told team A wins in 5 games, we're asked to find the probability of it losing the first game *under these terms*. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that you answered the question "what is the probability that team A *will* win the series in 5 games...". However the question you were asked was "given that team A *won* series in 5 games...".  The question, "What is the probability of Team A losing the first game?" is confusing because it is a question about the past asked in a way that suggests a future outcome. I've found that a number of math problems on MSE and elsewhere revolve around fairly subtle English constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we know the series lasted only five games, there are four possible outcomes:

$$
 1. LWWWW\\
 2. WLWWW\\
 3. WWLWW\\
4. WWWLW
$$

Thus, the probability that they Team A lost game one is $1/4$.

Comment: But if team A lost game one, how can you have arrangements 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: @AleksandrH No, we don;t know that A lost game one ... we just know they lost one game

Comment: But it says "What is the probability of Team A losing *the first game*?"

Comment: @AleksandrH you have to divide the number of **good** options (here 1) by the **total** number of options (4), because these options all have the same chance of occurring given that $A$ won in $5$ games.

Comment: @AleksandrH Right, the probability of that ... we are not certain of that. But given the information that A won in 5, we know that it has to be one of these 4 arrangements

Comment: But how could Team A have lost game one if we have the sequence WWWLW? That implies Team A lost game 4...

Comment: Edit: I'm stupid. These are the possible 4-1 wins. Only one of them is loss on first. Hence, 1/4. Thank you :P

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating $P(LWWWW)$, but you need to calculate the *conditional* probability $P(LWWWW|\text{Team A won in 5})$

That is, you are provided with *information* (Team A won in 5 games), and that means that the probability of event $LWWWW$ to happen (well, have happened) wil go up: it will be higher as compared to not knowing anything at all (other than the basic value of $p$ and that this is a best of 7)

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.

Comment: @AleksandrH You're welcome!  This is exactly why probability is so tricky ....

Answer (score 0):

GIven that we are in the situation that $A$ won in $5$ games, 
only 4 sequences of matches can have occurred:

$LWWWW, WLWWW, WWLWW, WWWLW$, all with the same probability.

So the chance we had the first is $\frac{1}{4}$.